# SecurityException: Permission Denial: While launching Activity via explicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-permissions

I was reading about [declaring permissions in activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities#dp)
. According to the documentation

> You can use the manifest's  tag to control which apps can start a particular activity. A parent activity cannot launch a child activity unless both activities have the same permissions in their manifest. If you declare a  element for a particular activity, the calling activity must have a matching  element.

To try this out, I created 2 sample Apps. First App will try to directly launch an activity of the second App, using an **explicit intent**, 
Also, the Second App will declare a permission for the particular activity which I'm launching from first App.

These are the steps I followed

1. Created 2 Apps (Say Sender And Receiver)
2. Added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="permission.SHARE_POST"/>` in the `Manifest` of sender
3. Now , from a button click of Sender App, I'm calling Receivers Activity called `ShareActivity` as follows

   ```
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("basics.android.com.androidbasics","basics.android.com.androidbasics.ShareActivity"));
       startActivity(intent);
   ```

   *NOTE: `basics.android.com.androidbasics` is the package name of the receiver*
4. Below given is the activity declaration in Second App's (Receiver) Manifest

   ```
          <activity
           android:name=".ShareActivity"
           android:exported="true"
           android:permission="permission.SHARE_POST"/>
   ```

Now, when I run both the Apps, and try to lauch `ShareActivity` from sender, I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=basics.android.com.androidbasics/.ShareActivity } from ProcessRecord{e09a1fc 26267:sender.android.com.sender/u0a925} (pid=26267, uid=10925) requires permission.SHARE_POST
```

Seems like the sender does't have the permission `permission.SHARE_POST` yet. But I have already declared it in the manifest of sender. 
Whats happening here?

Comment: Do both apps have the `<permission>` element defining `permission.SHARE_POST`?

Comment: No. Only the sender App has  `<uses-permission android:name="permission.SHARE_POST"/>`. Is that requred for both? Receiver only defines `android:permission="permission.SHARE_POST"` in the `<activity>` tag

Comment: They both need the element, if you want them to be installable in either order. Otherwise, the app with the `<permission>` *must* be installed first. Note that custom permissions truly suck on Android 4.4 and below, so I strongly recommend having a `minSdkVersion` of 21 or higher for these apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Now, I uninstalled both the Apps, added the `<permission>` element in both manifests. Installed again and tried,  Still getting the same error!!

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm running it on an Oreo device

Comment: Does your `<permission>` element have an `android:protectionLevel` attribute? Are both apps signed by the same signing key (e.g., your debug key)?

Comment: Are you possibly confusing `<permission>` and `<uses-permission>`? Note that they are different things, and the page you've linked doesn't seem to mention `<permission>`, which is necessary to actually define the custom permission. You might have a look at [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining#defining), too.

Comment: No, I haven't used both. I haven't signed the Apps since it's a sample App, I'm directly running it to my device/emulator

Comment: @MikeM. Ohh yes!!, so I was confusing `<permission>` and `<uses-permission>`. Now , Changed the `<uses-permission android:name="permission.SHARE_POST"/>` in the receiver to `<permission android:name="permission.SHARE_POST" android:protectionLevel="normal" />` . Now it's started working. But it's disappointing that there's no proper clarity in the Android documentation for a beginner to understand it in the proper way. Anyway thanks to you. You saved a lot of my time!!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using custom permissions is a fairly advanced thing to do in Android. The basic recipe is:

1. Decide what you want the permission name to be. It needs to be unique on the device. So, `permission.SHARE_POST` is not a good choice — add a prefix that is tied to your domain name or whatever else it is that you are using as the basis for your apps' `applicationId` values.
2. In the app that is defending itself with the permission, declare a `<permission>` element, with an `android:name` attribute holding the permission name from step #1. Optionally, give it an `android:protectionLevel` attribute (e.g., `signature`, so only apps signed by the same signing key can work together).
3. In the app that is defending itself with the permission, add an `android:permission` attribute on the component (e.g., `<activity>`), with a value of your permission name from step #1.
4. In the app that is looking to communicate with the app from step #3, add the `<uses-permission>` attribute, with an `android:name` attribute holding the permission name from step #1.
5. In both apps, set your `minSdkVersion` to 21, as there are security problems with custom permissions on older versions.

This will work, if the defender (step #2 and #3) will always be installed before the client (step #4). If you want the apps to be installable in either order, replace step #2 from above with:

2. **In *both* apps**, declare a `<permission>` element, with an `android:name` attribute holding the permission name from step #1. Optionally, give it an `android:protectionLevel` attribute (e.g., `signature`, so only apps signed by the same signing key can work together). Also, ensure that both apps are always signed by the same signing key, as otherwise they cannot both define the same permission.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I wish this was the explanation given in the official Android documentation!!