# ContentResolver Permission Denial

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions, android-contentresolver, android-handler

I am having two applications, let A and B. There is ContentProvider in A, with manifest declaration as follows,

```
<provider
            android:name=".LogProvider"
            android:authorities="com.xxx.LogProvider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.READ_XXX_LOGS"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:multiprocess="true"/>
```

Application B is receiving ContentResolver for the same. And App B have corresponding  also. But, whenever there is an Entry to content provider in App A, 
App B is receiving its onChange event. But, is having the following error.

```
I/XTSipListener: onChange, uri = content://com.xxx.LogProvider/error_logs/1
E/XTSipListener: onChange, SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.xxx.LogProvider from ProcessRecord{bb1084b 22087:com.xxx.AppB/u0a210} (pid=22087, uid=10210) requires android.permission.READ_XXX_LOGS or android.permission.READ_XXX_LOGS

W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.xxx.LogProvider from ProcessRecord{bb1084b 22087:com.xxx.AppB/u0a210} (pid=22087, uid=10210) requires android.permission.READ_XXX_LOGS or android.permission.READ_XXX_LOGS
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1712)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1662)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4935)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6083)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:2468)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:1476)
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(ContentResolver.java:1551)
W/System.err:     at com.xxx.AppB.contentobservers.XTSipListener.onChange(XTSipListener.java:86)
W/System.err:     at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:145)
W/System.err:     at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:216)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
E/XTSipListener: onChange: cur = NULL
```

AppB have target version 22. Which cant be upgraded due to some other functionalities.

Comment: Add the permissions to the manifest of application B e.g. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>`

Comment: already added. :(

Comment: On both applications? Or only application B?

Comment: No, permission added only in App B

Comment: App B is having the content Resolver, and App A is having the Content Provider

Comment: `android.permission.READ_LOGS` is already defined by the system, and regular apps cannot hold that permission. Define your own different `<permission>` in app A, that app B has a `<uses-permission>` for.

Comment: My permission is actually android.permission.READ_XXX_LOGS
Which I renamed since it is confidential.

Comment: OK, then make sure you're handling the custom permission correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54388386.

Comment: There is nothing :-/
The problem is App B is pre installed, and App A is installed later. So, App B already set the permission earlier before App A came into existence. Since, the target version is 22, we cant request permission also :(

Comment: You mean B already had `<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_XXX_LOGS" />`? Note that that's `<permission>`, not `<uses-permission>`.

Comment: You need to set android:exported="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I set android:exported="true" for my provider in App A.

Comment: @MikeM. App B is having a permission like this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_XXX_LOGS"/>

Comment: @MikeM. App A is having <permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_XXX_LOGS"       android:protectionLevel="normal" />

Comment: Unless B also has the `<permission>` element, then A would have to be installed first.